# How to interpret the RabbitMQ Message stats?

Tags: rabbitmq, monitoring, message-queue

I to want get and historize queue metrics for the "Enqueued, Dequeued an Size" (Terminology formerly met on ActiveMQ).
The *moving* charts provided in the management plugin are not enough for the monitoring that I need to do.

So with RabbitMQ, I'm getting data from https://rabbitmq-server:15672/api/queues/myvhost

This returns json.. for a queue, I can obtain real life production data like :

```
"messages":0,                    // for "Size"
"message_stats":{
         "deliver_get":171528,   // for "Dequeued"
         "ack":162348,
         "redeliver":9513,
         "deliver_no_ack":0,
         "deliver":171528,
         "get":0,
         "publish":51293         // for "Enqueued"
(...)
```

I'm in particular surprised by the `publish` counter:

- Its value can even decrease between 2 measures done with a couple of minutes of delay ! (see sample chart around 17:00)
- As you can see on my data, the `deliver_get` is significantly larger than the publish.

https://my-rabbitmq:15672/doc/stats.html doesn't give a lot of details that could explain what I actually notice.
Also, under the message_stats object that I obtain, I'm missing the some counters like `confirm` and `return` which could be related to the enqueuing.

**Are there relationships between these metrics ?** (like `deliver_get + messages = redeliver + publish`.. but that one doesn't work with my figures)

**Is there another more detailed documentation about these metrics ?**

[image]

Comment: I suggest asking this on the [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) mailing list.

Comment: I just posted the [same question on rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/rabbitmq-users/syUd9f499Ik)